# EigenObjectRecognizer Usage Help

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have made program that detects the face now what i have to do is Recognize them By googling up i came to know that it is done by EigenObjectRecognizer any one hae used it or can tell me how can i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been discussed here already:

[Using EigenObjectRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837523/using-eigenobjectrecognizer)

Or there is a libface library being developed for face detection and recognition:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libface/

Alex