# need help in C# OCR

Tags: c#, ocr

I am doing C# OCR for Chinese characters. I am required to do something like COCR2, which the users can use the small box to choose the character that the users want the system to recognize from the image. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using Emgu CV (a .net wrapper for OpenCV). http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

I specifically used the EigenObjectRecognizer class to do the image matching.

Comment: can u further explain on how u do that? because i'm new to this. or u show me any example of it if it is possible

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837523/using-eigenobjectrecognizer. His code might not be ideal for facial recognition but it is pretty close to what I have done really. However I use the 'FindMostSimilarObject' method to perform the recognition.