# How to train images with EigenObjectRecognizer

Tags: c#, emgucv

i am developing a C# app with emguCV and i am new to emguCV. I have seen this example in internet.

```
Image<Gray, Byte>[] trainingImages = new Image<Gray,Byte>[5];  
        trainingImages[0] = new Image<Gray, byte>("brad.jpg");
        trainingImages[1] = new Image<Gray, byte>("david.jpg");
        trainingImages[2] = new Image<Gray, byte>("foof.jpg");
        trainingImages[3] = new Image<Gray, byte>("irfan.jpg");
        trainingImages[4] = new Image<Gray, byte>("joel.jpg");
 String[] labels = new String[] { "Brad", "David", "Foof", "Irfan" , "Joel"}
  MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(16, 0.001); 

    EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
       trainingImages,
       labels,
       5000,
       ref termCrit);
        Image<Gray,Byte> testImage = new Image<Gray,Byte>("brad_test.jpg");

     String label = recognizer.Recognize(testImage);
     Console.Write(label);
```

what i need to know is how to train all images?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837523/using-eigenobjectrecognizer

Answer (score 0):

```
recognizer.Recognize(testImage) RETURN EigenObjectRecognizer.RecognitionResult
```

so you can try:

```
EigenObjectRecognizer.RecognitionResult helo = recognizer.Recognize(result);

Console.Write(helo.lable);
```

Comment: helo.lable or helo.label ??